# Unsupported operand type array / int after counting users

Tags: php, type-conversion, operands

I've got a problem that needs fixing and I can't seem to figure it out.

So, I use this method (part of method that's troublesome) to get total users when listed for pagination:

```
$up = Users::totalUsers($condition);
        $totalPages= ceil($up / App::config('rps'));
`
```

Then I go to model and count everyone:

```
    public static function totalUsers($condition)
    {
        $conn= DB::getInstance();
        $exp= $conn->prepare('
        
        select count(id) from users where concat(name,\'\',
        surname,\'\',email,\'\',username)
        like :condition
        
        ');
        $condition= '%' . $condition. '%';
        $exp->bindParam('condition',$condition);
        $exp->execute();
        return $exp->fetchAll();
    }
```

Tried adding PDO::PARAM_INT like

`('condition',$condition,PDO::PARAM_INT)`

but it also doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

`fetchAll()` returns an array, which you then try to divide by an integer. Try adding a `[0]` subscript or two to the last line of totalUsers() between the parentheses and the semicolon so it's like

```php
return $exp->fetchAll()[0][0];
```

This way totalUsers() will return an integer (well, actually a string which can be converted to integer) and you will be able to divide it by the other integer.